# Typed literal objects in TypeScript

Tags: extjs, typescript

I have a TS definition file for Ext JS containing function store.add(a : any) (it has many overloads so I guess this is to simplify the d.ts file). I want to pass it a literal object which implements a Person interface:

```
interface Person
{
  name: string;
  age: number
}

store.add(<Person>{ name: "Sam" });
```

This gives me intellisense but unfortunately it is just coercing the literal into a Person, without detecting the missing field. This works as I want:

```
var p : Person = { name: "Sam" }; // detects a missing field
store.add(p);
```

But is there a way to do this without a separate variable?

I realise this would be solved with 'fixed' definition files, but I think many Javascript libraries have too many overloads to allow this. I almost need a way to dynamically overload the function definition..! Would generics help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes generics seem to be the answer. In the definition file changing:

```
add?( model:any ): Ext.data.IModel[];
```

to

```
add?<T>( model:T ): Ext.data.IModel[];
```

Allows you to call

```
store.add<Person>({ name: "sam" });
```

And it correctly shows an error!